# Error en python: module' object is not callable

Tags: python, pdf

estoy usando el siguiente código de python y me manda un TypeError, comparto el código haber si alguien puede ver lo que no estoy viendo.

```
1. from pdfrw import pdfreader, pdfwriter
2. import os
3.
4. ruta_in = "C:\\Users\\Fermin\\Dropbox\\Mi PC (LAPTOP-95AJ4F8T)\\Documents\\fermin\\opciones\\proyectos\\johanes\\input"
5. ruta_out = "C:\\Users\\Fermin\\Dropbox\\Mi PC (LAPTOP-95AJ4F8T)\\Documents\\fermin\\opciones\\proyectos\\johanes\\output"
6.
7. def split(path, number_of_pages, output):
8.    pdf_obj = pdfreader(path)
9.    total_pages = len(pdf_obj.pages)
10.    writer = pdfwriter()
11.    for page in range(number_of_pages):
12.      if page <= total_pages:
13.        writer.addpage(pdf_obj.pages[page])
14.    writer.write(output)
15.    if __name__ == '__main__':
16.        split('reportlab-sample.pdf', 10, 'subset.pdf')
17.     
18.##-------------------------------------------------------------##
19.lista = os.listdir(ruta_in)
20.
21.for elemento in lista:
22.    if elemento.split('.')[-1] in ('pdf'):
23.         split(ruta_in+'\\'+elemento,3,ruta_out)
24.
```

obtengo el siguiente error

```
 line 8, in split
    pdf_obj = pdfreader(path)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Hola Fermím, tal vez esto te sirva de [ayuda](https://pdfreader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#tutorial-content).

Comment: Muchas gracias Marce Puente, ya lo estoy revisando, parece que es lo que busco, de nuevo mil gracias

Comment: Un placer ayudarte!!

Comment: Te dice que *pdfreader* no puede invocarse como función, quizá es *PdfReader* en lugar de *pdfreader*. Al igual de *pdfwriter* que deberia ser *PdfWriter*. Modifica el *import*

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan carlos, esto resulto ser la solución, ya esta jalando, de nuevo mil gracias